# Problem looping sound on android app

Tags: android, audio, loops

A bit of a problem has presented itself to me. I am trying to play a sound continously looping in my android app.

With MediaPlayer:
MP3 plays alright, but there is a gap at the end which does not exist in the file. I read it had to do with the decoder, and that ogg should work.
Tried using ogg, but still get the gap, which is definitely not on the file.

With SoundPool classes and ogg (using this fellow's interesting class: http://www.droidnova.com/creating-sound-effects-in-android-part-1,570.html),

the sound starts, and a fraction of a second later, it restarts. so I get a stutering half a second of the beginning of every file, without 
advancing further, because it is always going back to the beginning.

Is there something really wrong with media player and it's ability to loop audio? How about the freakishy stuttering soundpool?

Thank you very much for any assistance!

Comment: have you tryed ? player.setLooping(true);?

Comment: Yep, and it does loop, though it acts as if every file had about half a sec duration.

Comment: so go you getting solve your problem?

Comment: Try lowering the bitrate of your sound file. :)

Comment: It is knowing Android issue http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18756

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to looping soung (where sound with extension .ogg), instead of using sound pool lets try with Media player,This is the code i used to looping audio its work fine for me lets have a try,

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;


setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

try {
            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
            AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = assetManager.openFd("music.ogg");
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(),
                    descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            textView.setText("Couldn't load music file, " + e.getMessage());
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
```